# Reshard many big csv files to have each shard with the same number of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have many big csv files which share the same columns. The problem is that each of them have different number of rows and I need to reshard this data in such a way that each shard has the same number of rows.

This can be easily achieved with something like this:

```
num_rows_in_shard = 10**7
data = []
for f in sorted(glob.glob("dir/*.csv")):
    for index, row in pd.read_csv(f, index_col=0, usecols=[...]).iterrows():
        data.append((...))
        if len(data) == num_rows_in_shard:
           # save data into a new csv
           data = []

if len(data):
   # save leftovers
   data = []
```

But I am not sure whether this is the fastest option as iterating over the dataframe is not the fastest way to do things in pandas.

There is no particular reason to use pandas here. I use it here only because I need to select some particular columns from my csv.

Comment: You could probably use dask here. I'm thinking of something like a lazy concat which can then be chunked to return N rows at a time... pandas doesn't do this but dask probably would.